# How to clone from a local shared repsoitory using git svn

Tags: git, svn

Perhaps this is trivial or has been asked many times, but I was not able to make it work: I want to `git svn clone` a svn repo which is on a local drive (mounted as I: on Windows). But it does not work. From git bash I ran (on Windows):

```
git svn clone "i/path/2folder/Subversion"

Initialized empty Git repository in C:/myLocalFolder/.git/
Bad URL passed to RA layer: Illegal repository URL 'i/path/2folder/Subversion' at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 148.

git svn clone -HTTP "I:/path/2folder/Subversion"

git-svn - bidirectional operations between a single Subversion tree and git
usage: git svn <command> [options] [arguments]

  clone            Initialize and fetch revisions
                     --add-author-from
                     --authors-file, -A <arg>
                     ...
```

Using Windows' `cmd` and `net use` I found `I: = \\mydomain.ch\data$` and ran

```
git svn clone "git://mydomain.ch/data$/path/2folder/Subversion"

Initialized empty Git repository in myfolder/.git/
Bad URL passed to RA layer: Unrecognized URL scheme for 'git://mydomain.ch/data$/path/2folder/Subversion' at /mingw64/share/perl5/site_perl/Git/SVN.pm line 148.
```

Any ideas, how to clone such a repo?