# Setting up Git server on shared hosting

Tags: git, shared-hosting, git-server

I have tried to setup a Git server on my shared hosting website. If I use ssh connection, works perfectly, but when I try to clone the repository through HTTP it gives me this error:

```
fatal: repository 'https://git.lumito.net/ProgramOverflow.git/' not found
```

I have Python2 installed, but not Perl, so `git instaweb -d python` does not work. I also do not have Apache server, Ruby or pip installed.

What can I do?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why not clone over ssh?

Comment: @phd Yes, I can do that, but I want to share those repositories with others without ssh access.

Comment: Pure Python: https://pypi.org/project/klaus/, https://kallithea-scm.org/, https://pagure.io/pagure; Go: https://gogs.io/

Comment: @phd I do not have Python3 and/or pip installed on my server.

Comment: From the docs: `Git supports ssh, git, http, and https protocols (in addition, ftp, and ftps can be used for fetching, but this is inefficient and deprecated; do not use it). The native transport (i.e. git:// URL) does no authentication and should be used with caution on unsecured networks.` [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)

Comment: @phd Although it is `git svn` I have a similar problem. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62776408/how-to-clone-from-a-local-shared-repsoitory-using-git-svn). I don't feel like I can write an answer from the docs to this question ;-)